# Extrude Edges equivalent in Blender?

Tags: modeling, extrude

Is there any tools (perhaps addon) that resembles similar to what Extrude Edges do (from 3DS Max) in Blender with just single click?

Below is a screenshot from one of Viscorbel tutorial

[image]

EDIT : here's the video tutorial link, please check it at 01:45
[Classic Chair Viscorbel](https://vimeo.com/32613707)

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain, what does this function do exactly?

Comment: @Crantisz : i guess it is almost similar to bevel an edge, but our bevel edge in blender do not has ''depth'' parameter, instead profile which doesn' help at all

Comment: Still very unclear what 'Extrude Edges' is meant to do. Please [edit] your question and add a detailed description of how this function works.

Comment: here's the link guys = [link](https://vimeo.com/32613707)

time stamp : 01:45

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood right from the video here's what you're looking for.

Just select the edges by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> key to box select (in wireframe mode).

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> bevel the edges and with the mouse wheel scrolling make 1 loop at center.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> from the keyboard to deselect the edges so that only the center edge is selected.

With the edges selected press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (to unscale in the Z axis).

[image]

Comment: <kbd> Tags around keyboard keys please, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: @RayMairlot sorry i dont know the keyboard keys

Comment: You just have to put the kbd tag around the keys you mentioned in your answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs

Comment: that's it! thanks @atek
it's not a single operator though, but it's better than nothing..
thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same but a combination of bevel and scale operations.

select the edges then Press Ctrl + B to bevel, 
scroll up once to add a loop (more scrolls will add more loops)
, then select the middle loops and scale it up or down

[image]

Comment: thanks @Venay, so there isn't exactly similar tools?
i found that bevel edge could create quite like that, but it doesn''t has 'depth' parameter..

Comment: @selamatpagi yup, blender doesn't have that. the depth parameter is basically a form of scaling, so you'll have to scale the edges manually.

Scaling along the individual normals might yield better results.

Answer (score 1):

The tool looks like very similar to this is Inset (<kbd>I</kbd>). It has offset, that can be set by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

[image]

But it works only with faces.

Combination of 2 methods: Bevel <kbd>B</kbd> and Shrink/Flatten <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> exactly similar to this tool:

[image]

Comment: @selamatpagi, Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Addon found with similar functional (and even more functional): https://github.com/AlexMcKonst/MASC

[image]